# What is the best practice for pushing an AD in a Flatlist in Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, admob, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that displays post-like items (similar to Facebook posts), and all is working great, now that I have activated AdMob on my app, I want to push an ad in between the posts, for example, you see 3 posts, then an ad, then 3 posts, then an ad... etc.

What is the best way that I can achieve this? and which type of ad should I use? I have no experience in Admob whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You should at first read the Admob-documentation to decide, which Banner-Layout is the right for the ads you want to display. I suggest, that you use [Inline Adaptive Banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/inline-adaptive?hl=en). But be aware, that Banner Ads are not fixed size, so you definitely want to set a fixed height. On the other hand, you will see Ads, that are not full-width compared to your set height, so you have to think, how you will handle the blank spaces!

To render the Ads inside your FlatList, you should use the [ItemSeparatorComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent). To use this every 3 rows, you will have to check on each line, if it is "time" to display an Ad or not. By default, the ItemSeparatorComponent will display after every single row, so you want to play out 2 empty ItemSeparators after an Ad.

Comment: I tried doing this, but not possible to set a fixed height.  So when these ads load, they cause the screen to "bump" or jump due to the screen making space for the ad.  Not a great experience. 

Any advice?

Comment: How did you try to set the height for `ItemSeparatorComponent`?

Comment: Tried this, yeah but doesn't work with the Inline Adaptive Banners.  I decide to just use a large banner, which has static size, instead, and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything Conrad said. But...

if you can, opt for react-native-google-mobile-ads. This package has a BannerAd component that I use, that is great for this. There are also other sizes and options included in the package. With that, I'm able to determine the index of the item from the overall data array.

How I use is in my app is:

You're going to need these imports

```
import {
  BannerAd,
  BannerAdSize,
} from "react-native-google-mobile-ads";
```

In my FlatList,  my ItemSeparatorComponent is my Ad. ItemSeparatorComponent receives props. From those props, I use leadingItem and I supply every. This gives me the data for whatever item comes immediately before the separator component. With this data, I'm able to memoize a boolean value that determine if the ad should show based on the frequency (every) I supply.

```
function _FeedBannerAdComponent({every, leadingItem}) {

  const { data } = useContext(DataContext);
  const leadingItemIndex = data.indexOf(leadingItem) /// this gives the index of the leading Item to be used in should show function.

  .....

  const shouldShow = useMemo(()=>{
    let nbr = props?.every ?? 7 // default to every 7th element is every isn't supplied.

    if (leadingItemIndex % nbr === 0) return true; /// is the nbr element
    return false; /// isn't the nbr element
  },[every])

  ......

  if (!shouldShow) return null /// If false, do not show an ad.

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BannerAd
        size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER} /// Follow documentation for your specific size need, but this is what I needed. 
        unitId={/**/} /// Follow the docs... It's really simple.
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

For consistent styling, I added a styling to the View for consistency and to assist with performance of the FlatList. Without this, the ad would be shifted slightly off screen because of the padding from the FlatList, So I had to account for this in the margins of the Ad View container.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({}
  container: {
    marginLeft: -height * 0.01, /// this accounts for the padding in my flatlist because the width of the ad is full screen width. height is received from react-native's Dimensions.get("window")
    marginBottom: height * 0.008,
  },
)
```

And with all my FlatLists, I memoize my components.

```
const FeedBannerAdComponent = React.memo(_FeedBannerAdComponent)
```

Comment: What is leadingItem and what is the usage?

Comment: The leadingItem is the item in the data that comes immediately before the ItemSeparatorComponent. You can use this to determine if the separator component should be shown or if you need to know which item comes before the separator component.